# How to display characters per line in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, coding-style, ide

Is there an option in Eclipse or CDT to display the number of characters in each line of code or to highlight lines of code that exceed a specific length?

I am programming in C on Eclipse 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it.  Go to Windows -> Preferences.  Select Text Editors in the dialog box, and check the "Show print margin" option.  This will display a marker at a given column number that can allow the author to avoid exceeding a specific line length.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, on the bottom bar of the IDE, there is a number like: 1:1, 19:20, 50:100... this means that **"line:charactersInLine"**.

To complement not exceed too much the number of characters in line is a good practice. I'm the old days programming with very little monitors on resolution with 800x600, the number of 80 characters was a good one. But now with widescreen monitors a good number of characters in accord with many programmers is 120 characters per line.

Complementing the answer of @David Kaczynski:

> I found it. Go to Windows -> Preferences. Select Text Editors in the dialog box, and check the "Show print margin" option. This will display a marker at a given column number that can allow the author to avoid exceeding a specific line length.

After you activated **Show print margin** that shows the count of the lines, you can configure to:

```
Print margin column: 120
```